# iPod Classic 4th Generation drive failure?

Tags: hard-drive, backup, ipod, ipod-classic

My iPod Classic 4th Gen has worked well for many years. However, recently the hard drive has gone finicky. It will start sometimes, not others. When it doesn't boot, it just hangs on an Apple logo. Is it corrupted? I would like to make it run again, if possible. How should I go about this? I can use both a Mac and a Windows computer if needed.

I don't want to restore it if I don't have to. I had backed up all of the music, but there were photos on it that I would like as well. Is there any way for me to get these off?

Comment: What iPadOS version are you running on it?

Comment: The HDD is failing.  The only practical way to recover data from that phone is to remove the internal drive and attempt data recovery.  Depending on how important those photos are, you may need to send it to a service that specializes in data recovery.  As an aside, these are fairly easy to open and there are rather inexpensive kits available to swap out to an SSD.

Comment: It's an iPod Classic, not an iPad. I looked online and I didn't see a HDD adapter, but it doesn't mean there isn't one out there.

Comment: Looking at [iFixit.com](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/iPod+4th+Generation+or+Photo+Hard+Drive+Replacement/391), the iPod 4th Gen uses a 1.8" mini hard drive. Doing a search for "[toshiba mk2004gal usb adapter](https://www.google.com/search?q=toshiba+mk2004gal+usb+adapter&newwindow=1&sxsrf=AB5stBhzl2IyBuY_ap0XCbcCaWW1mZnZWA%3A1689256559076&ei=bwKwZJ2aBNanqtsPotqqwAs&oq=toshiba+mk2004gal&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQARgBMgsILhCABBDlBBCwAzIHCAAQHhCwAzIJCAAQCBAeELADMgkIABAIEB4QsANKBAhBGAFQAFgAYOMfaAJwAHgAgAEAiAEAkgEAmAEAwAEByAEE&sclient=gws-wiz-serp)" yields multiple possible adapters.

Comment: @agarza thank you so much! I'll try that and leave a comment about how it went! If you put it as an answer I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [iFixit.com](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/iPod+4th+Generation+or+Photo+Hard+Drive+Replacement/391), the iPod Classic 4th Gen uses a 1.8" mini hard drive. Via iFixit's repair guides, you could remove the hard drive to diagnose it.

A quick Google search for "[toshiba mk2004gal usb adapter](https://www.google.com/search?q=toshiba+mk2004gal+usb+adapter&newwindow=1&sxsrf=AB5stBhzl2IyBuY_ap0XCbcCaWW1mZnZWA%3A1689256559076&ei=bwKwZJ2aBNanqtsPotqqwAs&oq=toshiba+mk2004gal&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQARgBMgsILhCABBDlBBCwAzIHCAAQHhCwAzIJCAAQCBAeELADMgkIABAIEB4QsANKBAhBGAFQAFgAYOMfaAJwAHgAgAEAiAEAkgEAmAEAwAEByAEE&sclient=gws-wiz-serp)" which can be used to connect the iPod drive to a computer for diagnostics.

You may be able to repair the drive using Disk Utility but if the worst has happened, you can try to extract as much of your data as possible.